# Is there a way to send messages to buyers after their payment?,Is there a way to send a message to buyer after he bought something?

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to set up a script that sends automatically a message to people who buy something in my eBay store. I looked for something in eBay trading API references,
so maybe it's extremely obviously how to do it, but I'll appreciate any kind of help :)

```
when I use AddMemberMessageAAQToPartner it ignores your subject and uses.. '[sellerusername] has sent a question about : [messageType] for item #[item number], ending on [ending date in PDT] - [item name]' Our items don't end, they are for sale as long as we have quantity. What a useless piece of information to put in the subject in our case. What happened to the subject we sent in the API request? We are not sending a question. We are letting them know something about their shipment. We are sending info, an answer. Which API call sends a simple message to our buyer without saying it's a question. Be aware this call also adds your signature at the bottom in a different font.
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it's working fine when I used QuestionType `CustomizedSubject` in  `AddMemberMessageAAQToPartner` API
it will remove the `question` string from your `subject`.
see here.

[API request AddMemberMessageAAQToPartner API.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngALp.png)

[Message received with customized subject.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9VP1.png)

Now, this working perfectly fine

In this API's document all `QuestionType` possible `values` are mentioned.

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/QuestionTypeCodeType.html